# My application don't run properly when packaged as a Jar

Tags: java, swing, jar

I am following `file > export > runnable jar file`  to create a runnable jar file of my eclipse java project. when i run my application from eclipse, it works fine. [image]

But when i run it from the exported jar file, i get this. 
[image]

In the order and export tab inside the build path, i have checked all the externals jars that are needed. This is the ANT script that got created.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="create_run_jar" name="Create Runnable Jar for Project SERVER_SIDE with Jar-in-Jar Loader">
    <!--this file was created by Eclipse Runnable JAR Export Wizard-->
    <!--ANT 1.7 is required                                        -->
    <target name="create_run_jar">
        <jar destfile="C:/Users/nikitha/Desktop/server.jar">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader"/>
                <attribute name="Rsrc-Main-Class" value="Start"/>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/>
                <attribute name="Rsrc-Class-Path" value="./ mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar activation.jar comm.jar jSMS.jar jWAP.jar jWAP-src.jar mailapi.jar servlet.jar forms-1.3.0.jar"/>
            </manifest>
            <zipfileset src="jar-in-jar-loader.zip"/>
            <fileset dir="E:/eclipse juno/workspace/SERVER_SIDE/bin"/>
            <zipfileset dir="E:\eclipse juno\mysql-connector-java-5.1.24" includes="mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar"/>
            <zipfileset dir="E:\eclipse juno\jSMS-2.3.2\jSMS-2.3.2\lib" includes="activation.jar"/>
            <zipfileset dir="E:\eclipse juno\jSMS-2.3.2\jSMS-2.3.2\lib" includes="comm.jar"/>
            <zipfileset dir="E:\eclipse juno\jSMS-2.3.2\jSMS-2.3.2\lib" includes="jSMS.jar"/>
            <zipfileset dir="E:\eclipse juno\jSMS-2.3.2\jSMS-2.3.2\lib" includes="jWAP.jar"/>
            <zipfileset dir="E:\eclipse juno\jSMS-2.3.2\jSMS-2.3.2\lib" includes="jWAP-src.jar"/>
            <zipfileset dir="E:\eclipse juno\jSMS-2.3.2\jSMS-2.3.2\lib" includes="mailapi.jar"/>
            <zipfileset dir="E:\eclipse juno\jSMS-2.3.2\jSMS-2.3.2\lib" includes="servlet.jar"/>
            <zipfileset dir="E:\eclipse juno\workspace\SERVER_SIDE" includes="forms-1.3.0.jar"/>
        </jar>
    </target>
</project>
```

In my code, after displaying the comboBox for the port, the next step is to display the available serial ports by using the `CommPortIdentifier` Is there some problem in this step? Because according to the ANT script, comm.jar is included. So it shouldn't be causing a problem here.

Comment: *"What is causing this?"*  Most likely the code.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Where is your code? Did you think we have a crystal sphere and read the future in it?

Comment: `CommPortIdentifier` over 300 LOC and it it is *still* not compilable in J2SE!  I'll repeat *For better help sooner, post an **[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).***

Comment: As an aside, that source (the part of it which is included) has many `[unchecked]` & `[deprecation]` warnings.  **Do not ignore them.**

Answer (score 1):

Only reason i see this could happen is that you are populating these fields from some external text file which may not be found during runtime of your Jar execution. When you create you Jar file you must also add other dependent files/resources you need.If say Language dropdown is not displayed due to some resource not found Swing will not execute next instructions to display other contents on your container.

Can you provide what Errors/Exceptions or warning you are getting?

Comment: I see connect() before initialize(). Why do you need a database connection? I don't see you have used it anywhere. Just FYI if you are using JDBC driver you must add jdbc driver jar file when you create your applications executable jar file. Eclipse will not do this on its own.

Comment: if i `Package required libraries into generated JAR`, it does not show any warnings at all.  And if i `Extract required libraries into generated JAR` it gives me `duplicate entry` warnings.

Comment: I need database connection because all my language, region, message fields come from my database.

Comment: I would recommend remove connect() call from Send_Messages() constructor, make the jar again and run. If this works problem is due to JDBC driver only. First of all in project properties -> Java build path -> lIbraries check whether you have JDBC jar file(mysql-connector...) IF you have this then while you do export -> Jar file, add this jdbc driver jar file as a resource.

Comment: Problem is not with the JDBC driver. And whatever external jars i have in my build path, all of them are getting exported. I checked this by selecting "Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR" option that eclipse provides.